# Reporting tables (state transition tables) for Websphere Process server

Tags: websphere

I am trying to find the necessary tables in Websphere Process Server to do some basic productivity reporting. I an completely UN-familiar with WPS, but I assume that there has to be a core set of tables that capture state transitions of workflows.

Answer (score 0):

WPS flow data is managed internally by a DB2 Database, but i haven't seen any application that access directly to that data. WPS exposes a series of API's (EJB's, Web Services and RESTful Services) that allows applications to query WPS flow information but i don't think that approach is suitable for Reporting. More of that here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.bspace.help.api.rest.doc%2Frest%2Fwsprocessserver%2Findex.htm

What several companies does for Reporting and Monitoring is query WPS through IBM Websphere Business Monitor: it's a product designed to make reports about process instances in a very fancy way. It's a great product but it's also very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve by looking at the WPS database tables?

WPS tables should ideally be left alone. As suggested by Carlos look at the APIs exposed by WPS and use them for your purposes.

The database - "how it is used internally to store information"  is not publicly exposed so you won't find a great deal of information. There is information available on the database views which you can query on:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v6r2mx/topic/com.ibm.websphere.bpc.620.doc/doc/bpc/r6bpc_dbviews.html

I don't know the version of WPS that you are using. I am pointing you to the 6.2 docs. You should be able to locate them in 7.0 or what ever version you are using in your environment.

WB Monitor is a BAM tool that can be used for your BAM needs.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am trying to put together productivity reporting so I can answer questions like: "How many widgets did this team complete last month" and "How long, on average, does it take to process this kind of widget". I am aware of Monitor, but my IT dept wants $820K to build out the infrastructure to support it.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you mean by how many widgets the team completed this month.  Usually the term widget is used to represent items like a google widget. Business Space which is avaialble as part of WPS provides a number of widgets to work with. Please elaborate on what you mean by a widget. You can possibly use CEI events (that is generated by your BPELs and other components) and try and write an application around it. It would certainly take a lot of time and effort but that is a possible option for you.

Comment: Sorry, I guess my vocabulary is a little dated - I mean widgets to mean just units of work that a processor might perform... such as "how many cash transfers did this team approve in the last month"